# Can I create main menu without using built-in menu

Tags: menus, navigation

Can I create the main menu in the header.php file without using -
without Appearance--> Menus
without register_nav_menu()
without walker

What are the disadvantages?

My navigation markup:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light ms-auto pb-0 pe-0" style="z-index:343563;">
    <div class="container pe-0 m-0">
        <button class="navbar-toggler mq" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#main-menu" aria-controls="main-menu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-menu">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/index.php/home/">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/index.php/about/">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/index.php/projects/">Projects <i class="bi bi-chevron-down"></i></a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/index.php/contact/">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: You certainly can, with the main disadvantage being that the user won't be able to manage it.

Comment: Thanks for your attention and response Would there be any SEO or technical imipact, if wordpress or plugins are updated?

Comment: Sure, depending on the plugin, plugin updates could impact SEO, especially if the plugin interacts with content. If you'd like to have a discussion about SEO and it's impacts I'd recommend a discussion based channel like [The Loop Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6/the-loop), [WordPress IRC](https://make.wordpress.org/support/irc-support-channel/), or [The WordPress Forums](https://wordpress.org/support/forums/).

Comment: Google doesn't know how your site generated that HTML, wether it was hand written yourself or generated by the menu system, so how it was created is irrelevant for SEO purposes, only the end result matters. Howdy is right though this is more of a discussion point and you need to ask specific well formed questions here, this isn't a forum/messageboard!